# how debug the bug of urllib2 and arabic language?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I want code of html of below site
http://www.rasekhoon.net/media/3882/page1/
And i get it by below code

```
file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.rasekhoon.net/media/3882/page1/")
string= file.read()
```

and when i print it

```
    <div class="header" title="ظپط§غŒظ„ظ‡ط§غŒ ط³ط¹غŒط¯ ط­ط¯ط§ط¯غŒط§ظ† / ط³ط§ظ„ 1389 ط¨ط§ ظ…ظˆط¶ظˆط¹ 'ظ…غŒظ„ط§ط¯ ط­ط¶ط±طھ ط²ظ‡ط±ط§ ط¹ظ„غŒظ‡ط§ ط§ظ„ط³ظ„ط§ظ…'">
        <em>ظپط§غŒظ„ظ‡ط§غŒ ط³ط¹غŒط¯ ط­ط¯ط§ط¯غŒط§ظ† / ط³ط§ظ„ 1389 ط¨ط§ ظ…ظˆط¶ظˆط¹</em>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        ظ…غŒظ„ط§ط¯ ط­ط¶ط±طھ ط²ظ‡ط±ط§ ط¹ظ„غŒظ‡ط§ ط§ظ„ط³ظ„ط§ظ…
    </div>
    <div class="content richcontent" style="display:none;">
```

i want below result

```
<div class="header" title="فایلهای سعید حدادیان / سال 1389 با موضوع 'مناجات'">
        <em>فایلهای سعید حدادیان / سال 1389 با موضوع</em>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        مناجات
    </div>
    <div class="content richcontent" style="display:none;">
```

how i can fix it?

Comment: "how i can fix it?" The problem is far from obvious.

Comment: @Marcin: I suspect the output is a Latin-1 interpretation of UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing encoded data to your console, without altering the encoding.

The content-type header states the data is encoded in UTF-8, but you are printing it to a console using a Latin codec instead.

Decode the data to Unicode first:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.rasekhoon.net/media/3882/page1/")
html = file.read().decode('UTF8')
```

You *may* not be able to print the resulting Unicode value to your console; if it cannot encode the specific codepoints then you'll get `UnicodeEncode` exceptions. This is not a problem with the content, but with your console.